# How to sanitize the HTML on the server - WYSIWYG

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I've just installed [mpowaga:autoform-summernote](https://github.com/mpowaga/meteor-autoform-summernote) . In the instructions it says to sanitize the HTML on the server and sends you to atmosphere to install a sanitize package. I have installed `djedi:sanitize-html`however I can't find any instructions on how to integrate/use this with autoform and simple-schema. I assume I'm suppose to define this in the schema. I'm a noob so some guidance would be most appreciated.

If you would like me to post my schema or something else I can.

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) contains a guide to using the HTML sanitizer. Note that the guide is for Node, but it should work the same for Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code:

```
body: {
    type: String,
    label: "Enter Your Content here",
    optional: false,
    autoValue: function(){
        return Meteor.isServer ? sanitizeHtml( this.value ) : this.value;
    },
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
            type: 'summernote',
            class: 'editor' // optional
          //  settings: // summernote options goes here
        }
    }
}
```